# QueuedTaskScheduler leaks Tasks upon Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am trying to find out wherever it is me doing something incorrectly or that's a bug in the [Task Parallel Library Extras](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4179).
Below is the sample code which illustrates my scenario (extremely simplified, though). Once uncommented, `QueuedTaskScheduler`.`Dispose()` causes `Task`.`WaitAll()` to hang indefinetly as `tasks` array contains several (well, most of) tasks in `WaitingToRun` status.

I was under impression that `QueuedTaskScheduler`.`Dispose()` ought to either wait for all scheduled tasks to complete or abort them altogether.

Any idea how to fix existent behavior is welcome.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestTPLX
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckDisposeWorks()
    {
        var qts = new QueuedTaskScheduler();
        var ts = qts.ActivateNewQueue(100);
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    },
                cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, ts))
            .ToArray();

        cts.Cancel();

        // test hangs when line below is uncommented
        // qts.Dispose();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Update:
I managed to resolve hanging issue with removing `_disposeCancellation`.`IsCancellationRequested` checks inside `QueuedTaskScheduler`.`ProcessPrioritizedAndBatchedTasks()` method. However, this does allow only for execution of pending tasks, which, in some cases, might be not the desired behavior. Anyway, that could be solved elsewhere by means of `CancellationTokenSource`.`CreateLinkedTokenSource` and a simple wrapper around `Task`.`Run`.

Comment: What is surprising for you? Scheduler is that who handles the tasks, and you have to wait for them, and only after that dispose the scheduler. What is fix for you? Do not wait for all the tasks? Try to use the `WaitAny` instead of `WaitAll`

Comment: @VMAtm, you seem to misread 'extremely simplified' part. Assume this task scheduler is exposed via IoC and caller runs a task and then `Wait`/`await` for it. Currently, that 'wait' just hangs when scheduler gets disposed, which it might be, due to various reasons. In such case your idea 'to wait before dispose' means - don't use MS code, write your own scheduler with priorities and round-robin support. This is exactly what I don't really want to do until it is absolutely necessary. And by the way, the code hangs on 8-core box regardless of `WaitAll`/`WaitAny`

Comment: I did read that, but only after your comment it became clear yiu aren't talking about unit tests. Still, how do you expect the application will run tasks without a scheduler? What is the expected behavior? Why is the scheduler being disposed? Can you limit the clients to only create a tasks, not to dispose the scheduler? Too much uncertainty.

Comment: I'm looking for any non-hanging behavior, wherever it is cancellation of all pending tasks or wait until they all are executed. New tasks are not scheduled to this scheduler, so it is only question of shutdown. For now,  QTS just stops accepting new tasks, and has its queue in forever waiting state. I appeared to be wrong in the assumption that Microsoft TPL team has their code tested more than average joe.

Comment: You probably should introduce the answer for your question, not update

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly happy with the outcome, as having pending tasks cancelled is far more appropriate approach than one I've found, so I'd rather wait for a while - may be someone will have a solution soon.

Comment: In `TPL Dataflow`, if one `Complete` the `BufferBlock`, it doesn't allow new messages, but will not drop the existing ones. So, if you usesome simple logic like buffer block for storing the tasks, and action block for execute them, you'll get the behavior you want, I guess.

Comment: @VMAtm, I'd prefer not to add another package to the project but thanks for the direction - i'll see how that works and it might give me some idea I might use.